# Show that $X_n\overset{a.s}{\to}X$ and $M_n\overset{P}{\to}\infty$ implies $X_{M_n}\overset{P}{\to}X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

If $X_n\overset{a.s}{\to}X$,and $\{M_n\}$ are random variables whose range is $\mathbb{N}$ and $M_n\overset{P}{\to}\infty$,how to prove $X_{M_n}\overset{P}{\to}X$?

I tried to prove by contradiction.Otherwise,there exists $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ and a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $P(|X_{M_{n_k}}-X|>\epsilon)>\delta$,but how to derive the contradition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence of $(U_n)$ to $U$ in probability is equivalent to the fact that every subsequence of $(U_n)$ has a further subsequence converging a.s. to $U$. Your statement follows easily from this.